# Tradingview indicator

Tags: tradingview-api, indicator

make trading view indicator as follows,  For Buy - Value of Daily close greater than value of weekly upper bollinger band, Weekly RSI greater than 60, Weekly ADX greater than 18, Daily RSI greater than 60, daily positive DMI crossed above ADX, or daily positive DMI crossed above negative DMI, Plot Buy arrow on daily candle

I tried making with the help og chat GPT but did nit worked